# What happens to duplicate transactions that say pending, when one has confirmed?

Tags: transaction, wallet, address

For example, I withdrew 5 MIOTA from Bitfinex to my light wallet seed. I see 6 duplicate transactions, 1 of which went through and is reflected in my total balance, but the other 5 saying pending. What are these pending transactions, why do they exist, and is it okay that they are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are Reattaches of the same transaction. Only one of them can confirm, the others will stay pending forever. They'll eventually get pruned away during the next snapshot.